# change cell color based on condition

Tags: javascript

I have a condition that changes the background color of the table rows based on comparing values. I want to integrate another condition that compares two cells and returns a background color on only those cells..

I already have a loop running on the table

```
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
```

This is what i have but its applying the color results to the entire column rather than each cell..

```
         if (cells[10].innertext !== cells[11].innerText)
                cells[10].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                cells[11].style.backgroundColor = "red";

         else 
            (cells[10].innertext == cells[11].innerText)
                cells[10].style.backgroundColor = "green";
                cells[11].style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a capitalization issue. The first `innertext` should be `innerText`. And multiple statements must be put in a block to group them for a condition.

Also, to put a condition after `else`, it needs to be `else if`

```
        //-------------v
     if (cells[10].innertext !== cells[11].innerText) {
            cells[10].style.backgroundColor = "red";
            cells[11].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        //-------------v
     } else if (cells[10].innertext == cells[11].innerText) {
            cells[10].style.backgroundColor = "green";
            cells[11].style.backgroundColor = "green";
     }
```

Although logically the second condition isn't needed, so you could change it to:

```
     } else {
```

---

Additionally, `.textContent` is the standards version of getting text from an element. If you want wider browser support, you should do something like:

```
var text1 = cells[10].textContent || cells[10].innerText
var text2 = cells[11].textContent || cells[11].innerText
```

...and then use the variables for the comparison.

---

Lastly, there's no need to be so verbose with:

```
cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
```

You can just use this instead:

```
rows[i].cells
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/)?  It will allow you to bind your values to the grid and then subscribe to events that happen to them.

Comment: This is a big truck to carry a small problem.